# Problema de transition en CSS

Tags: css

Tengo un div que tiene de estilo esto:

```
div{
  transition: 1s;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
div.active{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Pero a la hora de cargar la página se ve el proceso del div en movimiento hacia el `-100px`, y no quisiera que se mostrará ese movimiento. ¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Los estilos están en diferentes archivos.

Comment: tenes que redactar mejor tu pregunta, porque en base a tu pregunta esta la respuesta abajo, pero no te satisface porque necesitas el movimiento pero en determinado tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar ver la animación tenes que mover la propiedad `transition` al selector `div.active`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('div').classList.toggle('active')
});
```

```css
div {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

div.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Texto de prueba</div>
<button id="btn">Animar</button>
```